# two non type template parameter constants

Tags: c++, templates

maybe I don't quite understand what's going on behind the scenes, but in my understanding, the compiler is just injecting the parameters and evaluating at compile time,

I'm trying to make a matrix class that uses templates and overloaded operators to enforce matrix multiplication rules with the compiler,

```
template<unsigned int ROWS,unsigned int COLS>
class Matrix{
    public:
        Matrix<ROWS,COLS>(){
...
```

doesn't compile though

are multiple integers as arguments not supported? or is there some syntax that I can use to achieve the desired results

Comment: What compiler error do you get? Can you complete that class definition and maybe provide something trying to instantiate it to make this a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't think that template syntax should be used here: `Matrix<ROWS,COLS>() {`

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/CNuKRM).  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @KamilKoczurek `Matrix()` would do because of the injected class name, if that's what you mean, but the full `Matrix<ROWS,COLS>()` is also allowed.

Answer (score 0):

wow I didn't expect to get responses so fast! 
after seeing some of the comments, I re-entered the code and it worked, so I guess I must have mis-typed something